# Derivative of a function has orthogonal columns

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was looking into a lecture note online, and we have this function
$T(r, θ, φ) = (r \sinθ \cosφ, r \sinθ \sin φ, r \cos θ)$. After calculations, I know that the columns of the derivate of this function are orthogonal to one another. What is a geometric interpretation of this fact?